# SQL Query for matching starting 3 words in SELECT Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with a column filled with some addresses.
I have a form where a user inserts his address and I search in the table to check if the address exist or not.
So the address have several parts 
*For Example :*
This is an address in database
**20907 ASHBURN HEIGHTS DR.**
See it has 4 words. I just want to search for starting three parts, so if a user enters
**20907 Ashburn Heights ABCD**. It should take it.

I have already sliced my user input in first 3 words via PHP.

```
$myinput = implode(' ', array_slice(explode(' ', $myinput), 0, 3));
```

My current Query:

```
SELECT * FROM wp44_predefined_address WHERE Address1 LIKE '".$myinput."%'
```

LIKE Operator is not helping.
If I enter just **ASHBURN HEIGHTS** Then also it is matching the input which it shouldnt. It should only match first 3 words in the predefined addresses.

Comment: You can use LIKE & % in your query. SELECT * FROM TABLE-NAME WHERE address LIKE 'USER-ENTERED-VALUE%';

Comment: See [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/pattern-matching.html)

Comment: @Ukasyah No. LIKE Operator is not helping. If I enter just ASHBURN HEIGHTS Then also it is matching the input which it shouldnt. It should only match first 3 words.

Comment: There's nothing can help you except LIKE operator :)

Answer (score 0):

SELECT CASE WHEN c.Add1 = userInputAdd1 AND c.Add2 = userinputAdd1 THEN "Data Allready Exists" END 
  FROM wp44_predefined_address 
 WHERE Add1 = "Your First Input"
   AND Add2 = "Your Second Input"